# Jquery setDefaults doesn't find the jquery object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to set the jquery validate setDefaults() method from the highlight.js file in my bundlesConfig.cs file, but the exception being thrown says that jquery or the $ is null!

It's thrown on this line here

> $.validator.setDefaults(defaultOptions); // $ is null

Here is my bundleconfig and highlight.js file

> bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
>                           "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
>   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
>                           "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
>   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
>                           "~/Scripts/highlight.js"));

```js
var defaultOptions = {
  validClass: 'has-success',
  errorClass: 'has-error',
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest(".form-group")
      .removeClass(validClass)
      .addClass('has-error');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest(".form-group")
      .removeClass('has-error')
      .addClass(validClass);
  }
};

$.validator.setDefaults(defaultOptions);

$.validator.unobtrusive.options = {
  errorClass: defaultOptions.errorClass,
  validClass: defaultOptions.validClass,
};
```

Comment: Are `$(element).closest` also return `$ is null` error? If they're not null, then either you're duplicating bundle names (overriding the previously created one) or you're missing `Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` inside layout. If they're having null values, check if `Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` added into layout page.